# How to serve files from parent directories?

Tags: apache

I am building a web application, the directory structure is little typical.

The web server is serving files from `/var/www/html/`.

I am storing users files in `/homes/some/dir/users/username/`.

Is this smart way to do this?

How do I configure my webserver to serve files from `/homes/some/dir/users/`?

Please suggest some good links to organize directory structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DocumentRoot command to point to your directory.

```
DocumentRoot "/homes/some/dir/users/username/"
```

See here for details: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot

From the name it looks like you want your home directory as basis for serving web pages. This is not a good idea as this may expose other sensitive files that typically reside there (shell history just to name one).

Comment: then what is the best way to organize directory structure ?

Comment: using /var/www/html is good practice. You should copy your html files from you home dir to there.

Comment: I miss context over there, users upload files to "/homes/some/dir/users/username/" now I have to access them, my DocumentRoot set to "/var/www/html".

Comment: Please refer to this for information on how to link "external" files so they appear to be under your DocumentRoot: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/urlmapping.html#outside

Comment: how can I get using htaccess